# django delete self and not a self referential entity

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following sample models:

```
class Note(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    author = models.OneToOneField(User)
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    similar_note =  models.ForeignKey("self", related_name='similar_note', null=True, blank=True)
```

Say there are two notes Winner and Loser.

Loser has a field similar_note that points to Winner Note.

When I delete any of the two, both gets deleted, how do I prevent this from happening?
I have tried doing the same from the django admin interface as well, it happens from there as well.

PS: I am using django1.2, please don't advice to upgrade, there are way too many constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects):

> When Django deletes an object, by default it emulates the behavior of
>   the SQL constraint ON DELETE CASCADE -- in other words, any objects
>   which had foreign keys pointing at the object to be deleted will be
>   deleted along with it.
>
> This cascade behavior is customizable via the on_delete argument to
>   the ForeignKey

Please check the [on_delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) parameter for model field:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Comment: i dont want to `SET_NULL` i want the values in the fields to remain intact.

Comment: By using `on_delete=models.SET_NULL` on `similar_note` the `winner_note` should be there with the value intact. Only the value of `similar_note` is gone.